# How to create logo(picture) and size

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I create new module not inherit, I create header but the logo still not show, how to fix it?

```xml
<div class="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img t-att-src="'static/src/img/L.png'" style="max-height: 65px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row zero_min_height">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<img t-att-src='/your_module_name/static/src/img/L.png' style="max-height: 65px;"/>
```

hope it will help you.